# Trying to create a randomized "solar system"

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Here is the Planet class:

```
public class Planet extends CelestialBody {

 private static Random r = new Random();
    private static Star star;

    public Planet(Star star, int orbitRadius, int x, int y){
        name = "PLACEHOLDER";
        radius = Tools.intBetween(Settings.MAX_PLANET_SIZE, Settings.MIN_PLANET_SIZE);
        color = Tools.rObjFromArray(Settings.PLANET_COLORS);
        this.star = star;
        this.orbitRadius = orbitRadius;
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
    }


    public static Planet createNewPlanet(Star star, int orbitRadius){
        int px = (int) (star.x + orbitRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(r.nextInt(360))));
        int py = (int) (star.y + orbitRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(r.nextInt(360))));

        return new Planet(star, orbitRadius, px, py);
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        //Draw orbit
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawOval(star.x - orbitRadius, star.y - orbitRadius, orbitRadius * 2, orbitRadius * 2);

        //Draw planet
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    }
}
```

---

```
orbitRadius = distance from planet to star (random);

radius = planet's radius (random)
```

[image: result]

Ask in the comments if you need any more code, and I know this is a noob question, but I just can't figure out why the orbits dont line up with the planets. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code looks fine at first glance. Can you maybe post the rest of the Planet class? If you want to make it even easier for people to help you can try to make a [Minmal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what the problem is.

Comment: I edited in the entire class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following two lines:

```
int px = (int) (star.x + orbitRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(r.nextInt(360))));
int py = (int) (star.y + orbitRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(r.nextInt(360))));
```

Because you call `r.nextInt(360)` two separate times, you get a different random number each time.

The consequence is that the x and y coordinates are for different angles, I think it's clear why this would be a problem.

The solution is very simple: call `r.nextInt` once and save the result:

```
double randomAngle = Math.toRadians(r.nextInt(360));
int px = (int) (star.x + orbitRadius * Math.cos(randomAngle));
int py = (int) (star.y + orbitRadius * Math.sin(randomAngle));
```

I think this should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It's so obvious but I just couldn't figure it out.